# Electric meter with Arduino and RS485 module

Tags: arduino-uno, rs485

I'm a Arduino newbie. I have an Electric meter with an RS485 output. I want to get the MeterID value over the RS485 module and the Arduino. I just have document from manufacturer.

```
Sent by computer : 68 99 99 99 99 99 99 68 01 02 67 F3 C3 16. 
Return from meter : FE 68 99 99 99 99 99 99 68 81 08 67 F3 A6 9B 34 4B 33 33 6F 16.
```

My Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SSerialRX        10
#define SSerialTX        11
#define SSerialTxControl 3
#define RS485Transmit    HIGH
#define RS485Receive     LOW

SoftwareSerial RS485Serial(SSerialRX, SSerialTX);
byte request[] = {0x68, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x68, 0x01, 0x02, 0x67, 0xF3, 0xC3, 0x16}; 
int byteRead;

void setup()   
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  RS485Serial.begin(1200);
  pinMode(SSerialTxControl, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive);
  delay(20);
  Serial.println("Get Meter Address App");
}
void loop()   
{
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Transmit);
  RS485Serial.write(request, sizeof(request));
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive);
  delay(2000);
  if (RS485Serial.available()) 
  {
    byteRead = RS485Serial.read();
    Serial.println(byteRead, HEX);
  }
}
```

Serial Monitor show:
[image]

I'm using combo like this topic [modbus-rtu-controller-monitoring-with-arduino-and-rs485-module](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50645/modbus-rtu-controller-monitoring-with-arduino-and-rs485-module). My code is in C# below. I used the code before and it worked fine, but on the computer I use a COM port (Baudrate 1200, data 8bits, Parity EVEN, Stopbit 1) with an RS485-R232 converter:

```
#Send data
dataOUT = WriteData("68 99 99 99 99 99 99 68 01 02 67 F3 C3 16");
serialPort_Meter.Write(dataOUT, 0, dataOUT.Length);

#WriteData method
private static byte[] WriteData(string hex)
{
return hex.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
}

#Read data
private static string ReadData(SerialPort serial)
{
byte[] buffer = new byte[serial.BytesToRead];
serial.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2} ", buffer[i]);
return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you don't have delays in C#. why do you have delays in Arduino?

Comment: It's still blank

Comment: with delay you missed the data. without delay you check too early

Comment: Please advise me

Comment: Hi Cosi Nguyen. Can you share some details about the electric meter you are trying out this with? Even the document you are referring to can be helpful to understand.

Comment: Hi Sumit Panse. My meter is http://electrique.com.sg/?product_cat=amsys. This is private company of my country and document don't public in the internet

Comment: Hello all, I figured out the reason is because SoftwareSerial's default library does not support connection configuration. I use CustomSoftwareSerial and fixed it by connecting the required data bit, stop bit, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [readBytes](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamreadbytes/) would do the same as your C# code. `readBytes` is blocking. It will wait for every byte until timeout. Default timeout is 1 second. If the count of bytes is smaller then the size of the buffer, it will wait a second after the last byte received. You can set the timeout with `RS485Serial.setTimeout(500);` (500 milliseconds for example).

```
void loop()   
{
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Transmit);
  RS485Serial.write(request, sizeof(request));
  RS485Serial.flush();
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive);
  int recvLen = RS485Serial.readBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  for (int i = 0; i < recvLen; i++) {
    Serial.println(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still blank. I think issue from the sent request ?

Comment: You mean i need create another function and call in loop() ?

Comment: Thank your advise my new code to fix this problem

Comment: #include <CustomSoftwareSerial.h>

CustomSoftwareSerial RS485Serial(SSerialRX, SSerialTX);

RS485Serial.begin(1200, CSERIAL_8E1);

Comment: sorry, I overlooked that you set non standard serial parameters